# Box not expanding height wise as min-height is already given

Tags: css

My class goes like this to expand the div dynamically as min-height is given. May i know what goes wrong with this.

```
.gil_Individual_FormPanelBg
{   
    width:500px;
    min-height:50px !Important;
    float:none;
    margin:5px auto;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    border:Solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    -border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -Moz-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

Comment: post a link to your page, or setup your page on jsfiddle.com so we can see what your problem is. from your question i have no idea.

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle, and I see no problems with it expanding.  http://jsfiddle.net/kqyHV/

Comment: Basically i created this class to make a bg of a form which later on i want to use for different places... That is why i created this class with min-height as my forms might vary in height wise... But my div above created is not enlargin height wise as desired...May i know what goes wrong.

Comment: see this link http://jsfiddle.net/7NNqB/1/#run

Comment: When i am putting divs from wrapper div inside table it expands finely...But i want this without table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shabir, looks as though you have got a whole heap of `float:left`'s when there is no need.

Try this **updated CSS**:

```
.gil_Individual_FormPanelBg
{    
    width:500px;
    min-height:50px;
    margin:5px auto;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    border:Solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    -border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -Moz-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.gil_Individual_FormWrapper
{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;    
    margin:2px auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.gil_Individual_FormRow
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:20px !Important;
    margin:3px 0 0 0;
    padding:0px;
}

.gil_Individual_FormLable
{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:15px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:Normal;
    color:#3B5998;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.gil_Individual_FormCtrl
{
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    min-height:15px !Important;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:Normal;
    color:#333;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

HTML stays the same. If you are going to add the class float. Consider creating a clear class to place after the floated DIV.

Class something like this:

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:1px;
}
```

After reviewing the link you posted, it does look like you have probably over complicated the build but hopefully it should work the way you want it to now.

Dan

Comment: Mr Dan, Thx for your help... May i know hw to get this effect without over complicating

Comment: Can you supply a flat image of what you want to achieve and I will take a look into the CSS and HTML for you and see if we can simplify things =)